# Ruby How to iterate over an array of instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this array from `Order.all`

```
    [#<Order:0x00007f1d219f7028 id: 1, time: "01.00", amount: 21, created_at: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 17:44:41 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 17:44:41 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Order:0x00007f1d219f6ee8 id: 2, time: "02.00", amount: 23, created_at: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 17:44:41 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 17:44:41 UTC +00:00>]
```

When I do `Order.all.first[:time]` I get `"01.00"` so that 'works'.

But when I do

```
a = []
Order.all.each do |e|
  b = Array(e[:time])
  b << e[:amount]
  a << b
end
```

I just get the above array again???

How do I iterate over the array to get
`[['01.00', 21],  ['02.00', 23]]`

Comment: @Ursus has given a good answer but in future consider waiting longer before awarding the greenie. Quick selections can discourage other answers and imo are discourteous to those (if any) still working on their answers. There's no rush. Many members wait at least a couple of hours, sometimes much longer, before selecting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that. Try this one

```
Order.all.pluck(:time, :amount)
```

A more verbose and expensive way to do it

```
Order.all.map { |order| [order.time, order.amount] }
```

Even more verbose, probably what you're trying to do

```
result = []
Order.all.each do |order|
  result << [order.time, order.amount]
end
```

Comment: How about also adding the `each_with_object` option?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just before the last one maybe. Next time :D

Comment: With or without `each_with_object` it saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may be correct. You should keep in mind that `#each` return the enumerated collection. The collection of orders in your case.

The result you are expecting is the variable `a`